# How to get the last match of a string over a column and print the subsequent column's value in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, string-matching

I am forced to use excel for work reasons and I am a novice with that...so forgive me for the stupid question.
I have an excel sheet like that:
[image]

I would like to have in cell B53 (the green coloured one) the last satus registered in column F for SN0006 --> status "READY". So, steps are:

1. Find all the occurrences that matches cell A53 content, id est SN0006, in the column B ("SN")
2. Take the last occurrence (at the n-1 row). Dunno if it could help but consider that column "EVENT ID" is ordered in an ascending manner so that the last occurrence will have a higher index
3. Print in cell B53 the content of the column "STATUS" respect to the last SN0006 occurrence row.

Until now I was able to print the STATUS of the first SN0006 occurrence "BRING UP" in that way:

> =INDEX(F39:F51;MATCH(A53;B39:B51;0))

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Use something like `=LOOKUP(2,1/(B39:B51=A53),F39:F51)` or go with the newer `XLOOKUP()` function.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) which will work in Excel 2007 and later

```
=INDEX(F39:F51,MAX((A53=B39:B51)*ROW(B39:B51))-38)
```

Comment: Could you explain the Logic??? (for example...where the last value 38 comes from????) Moreover it doesn't work in my case...

Comment: The `(A53=B39:B51)*ROW(B39:B51)` produces an array of either row numbers where the value in A53 is found, or 0s otherwise; it's enclosed in the MAX() function because you are interested in the 'highest' row number - the 38 is deducted because the smallest result from the row function will be 39, so subtracting 38 results in 1, the lowest possible valid value for the row argument of the INDEX() function.

Comment: Did you enter it using CTRL+Shift+Enter (rather than Enter key alone) ? (that's why I included the link)

Comment: It was my fault...it works fine! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I also find a way but I didn't understand how it works...

> `=INDEX(F39:F51;MATCH(2;1/(B39:B51=A53)))`

Comment: `B39:B51=A53` results in an array of TRUE and FALSE values according to whether there's a match or not; dividing these into 1 makes the array into a series of 1s or errors - in looking for 2 (a value bigger than any in the array), the `MATCH()` function returns the position of the last 1 in the array, and this then becomes the row argument for the `INDEX()` function